# Check specific time if within 5 minutes run additional method

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a program that is ran every 30 minutes 24/7.  However at 1:30 am I need the original method to run and then I need to run an additional method as well.

I know `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay` will give me the current time.

But our automizer if backed up could potentially run it 5 minutes from 1:30 so tell the program to run my additional method if the time is between 1:30 am and 1:40 am.

Comment: how do I be say and say?

Comment: @bump fixed with edit.

Comment: Nothing a variable of type *bool* could not fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can determine if the current `TimeSpan` is between two specified `TimeSpan` times.

```
    TimeSpan currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

    TimeSpan earliest = new TimeSpan(1, 30, 0); // 1:30 AM
    TimeSpan latest   = new TimeSpan(1, 40, 0); // 1:40 AM

    if (currentTime >= earliest && currentTime <= latest)
    {
        // It's between 1:30 AM and 1:40 AM - Do Something!!
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = DateTime.Now;

var hour = date.Hour;
var minutes = date.Minute;

if ((hour == 1) && (minutes >= 30) && (minutes <= 40))
{
    Console.WriteLine("do it now");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime thatSpecialTime = DateTime.Today.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 35, 0));
TimeSpan howClose = thatSpecialTime - DateTime.Now;
if (5 >= Math.Abs(howClose.TotalMinutes))
{
   //do your extra method    
}
```